# Unable to sore lines of an http-text file in list python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
url="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt"
data=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

list_line=[str(x) for x in data]

for line in list_line:
    line.replace("b'","")
    line.replace("\\n","")
    line.replace("\\t","")
print (list_line)
```

It is generating list like this:

["b'-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----\n'", "b'Proc-Type: 2001,MIC-CLEAR\n'", "b'Originator-Name: webmaster@www.sec.gov\n'", "b'Originator-Key-Asymmetric:\n'", "b' MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen\n'", "b' TWSM7vrzLADbmYQaionwg5sDW3P6oaM5D3tdezXMm7z1T+B+twIDAQAB\n'", "b'MIC-Info: RSA-MD5,RSA,\n'", "b' EvPdKfnjzBIjWkEk2RgNCk1/52qXomHpN+LDwL/XTT/XBuAzk70AYYrsxlQbyiqr\n'", "b' V5559QRyTgPe9PfVt0db9Q==\n'", "b'\n'", "b'0000950170-98-000413.txt : 19980309\n'", "b'0000950170-98-000413.hdr.sgml : 19980309\n'"]  <----sample

I want to remove b',\n and \t , string split and replace not working, how to do it?

Comment: Tip: `line.replace()` does not replace in-place, it returns a new string, which you throw away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to replace things, decode the data as `utf-8` to get the resulting text:

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
text = data.decode('utf-8')
text = text.replace('\t', '')   # Remove tabs if still needed
print(text)
```

This would show the start of the text as:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----
Proc-Type: 2001,MIC-CLEAR
Originator-Name: webmaster@www.sec.gov
Originator-Key-Asymmetric:
 MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen
 TWSM7vrzLADbmYQaionwg5sDW3P6oaM5D3tdezXMm7z1T+B+twIDAQAB
MIC-Info: RSA-MD5,RSA,
 EvPdKfnjzBIjWkEk2RgNCk1/52qXomHpN+LDwL/XTT/XBuAzk70AYYrsxlQbyiqr
 V5559QRyTgPe9PfVt0db9Q==

<SEC-DOCUMENT>0000950170-98-000413.txt : 19980309
<SEC-HEADER>0000950170-98-000413.hdr.sgml : 19980309
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0000950170-98-000413
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  10-K405
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:
```

If you want a list of lines add:

```
lines = text.splitlines()
```